# Create empty proxy bean from interface

Tags: java, spring

There is the interface of the service:

```
@Component
public interface TestService {
    @Transactional
    @AnyTestAspect
    void test();
}
```

Is it possible to create empty instance of this interface as the spring bean? It is necessary does not remove all functionality with spring aop.

As the result need to get spring bean which is instance of this interface with empty method body and with all logic with spring aop.

Comment: I don't know of a standard way in Spring, but I'm sure an extension to Spring could be created to allow it.  But why?  Why not just create the few lines of code necessary to define an empty implementation of this class as a bean?  What would you want it to look like instead?  I think any other mechanism would just be more obscure given how simple it is to create an empty implementation bean.

Comment: @CryptoFool in out project we have approach which load dynamically spring beans into context from groovy descriptor. This descriptor has any methods with any aop annotations for validation and another calls to external services. I agree that this requirements is very specifically, but we need it to solving problems.